# How to get the value of a primary key using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, primary-key, attr

> Country Name

and

> Country Id

are two fields in my HTML page. I have used

```
<input id ="txtCountry" maxlength ="20" />
```

for my country text-box and nothing for my country id.

Now, I need to store and retrieve Country Id. To update the record I have a jquery and that needs my CountryId, how can I get that just using my input field.

```
$('txtCountry').attr('what comes here');
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is?

Comment: where is `country name` and `country id` on your page?

Comment: I want to store countryid in my html form, I have only one control in my html form. How to do it ?

Comment: @Neal : Updated my post again

Comment: @Neal : I have only country name in my page, I dont have country id. I am asking help how to add country id in my page(some type of control like thing to store country id in my html page). Can you get now ?

Comment: no. your question is very vague. **vote to close**

Comment: It seems he wants to store arbitrary data in the HTML element.

Comment: @Rocket - you got it ..Tell me man..how to do it...

Comment: @Neal _ if you dont get it, dont delete the post. Some other will give me answer, I want. :(

Comment: @nandu.com: Check out jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what you're trying to do, but I suspect that you are trying to populate that input field on page load to make it possible for your user to update the value in the database.

I'm not sure what server techonology/framework you're using but to populate the textbox you would do something like this:

```
<input id ="txtCountry" maxlength ="20" value="CountryName" countryId="CountryId" />\
```

Then in jQuery you could access the country name like this:

```
$("#txtCountry").val();
```

And access the country id like this:

```
$("#txtCountry").attr("countryId");
```

Comment: I suggest you use HTML5 `data-` attributes.  `data-countryId="CountryId"`, then you can do `$("#txtCountry").data("countryId");`.

Comment: Thanks.Nick. This is what i am asking for.

Comment: Thanks Rocket. I was struggling to implement the code you gave in old version of html. You helped me at right time.

Comment: @Rocket, Is that cross browser? IE7/8+ etc? I haven't looked much into CSS3 or HTML5 as i'm assuming there are still a lot of users out there using older browsers.

Comment: I'm not sure if IE7/8 can use HTML5.